# using React hooks how can I call a function after setState is execute. A callback used to be a parameter, ie setState(val,callback)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my app I have a form where I need to discard or save changes to data that is in state. I call setState on discard to revert the data and also on save. I would like to call a function after I have set the state , and its value not be stale.

Therefore I would need a different callback per call to setSate (onSaved & onDiscarded in this instance). This used to be possible in previous versions of React.

I realise useEffect is the answer for many of these scenarios however, when setState is called in multiple places, useEffect doesnt know the context, just that state has changed. I dont know if state was changed do to Discard or Save.

I'm very curious as to what the community would recommend as best practise in this scenario.

Please see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-set-state-callback-forked-0ptod4?file=/src/BaseComponent.tsx)

Comment: You either add your desired "useEffect logic" in the "onSave"/"onDiscard" callback (recommended), or add additional status flag to indicate which kind of update triggered the change.

Comment: @DennisVash as soon as you have more than 1 concurring tasks running neither option is viable. Putting the logic into the "onSave"/"onDiscard" callbacks is no option, because state updates are async and you can't access the updated state. Using a flag is no option either, because you have multiple (more than 1) of these flags flying around simultaniously and have no correlation which one corresponds to which state update. Frankly, the more I learn about the do's and don'ts of react the less I understand how I'm supposed to deal with this issue.

Comment: I'm getting the sense that this is a job for [useReducer](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useReducer).

Comment: @Thomas "as soon as...", no one mentioned anything about multiple tasks or concurrent flows, and either way, you still can solve it, even if states "running async" you still know if there is one in flight, and if you want to escalate, you can go through server and make sure the requests are in sync. Don't see any particular unknown scenario here

Comment: Hi same team as poster, 1 piece of state 2+ actions can't figure out another way to do it without introducing more state (i.e. formStatus and performing useEffect on that).

Comment: @DennisVash Thanks for the feedback, it is appreciated. Can you explain the "You either add your desired "useEffect logic" in the "onSave"/"onDiscard" callback (recommended)". With this being recommended I'd love to be clear on that. Additional state id like to avoid if possible unless it simple is the cleanest way.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said for most cases `useEffect()` would be the preferable solution.

I would go ahead with `setState()` anyway. Then I would go ahead with the rest of my code, and just use the value I'm setting, to the success/discard functions.

```
const myFunction = (myValue) => {
  setValue(myValue); // I set the value anyway, I don't care when it renders
  if (myValue) { // some condition
    discard(); // IDK if you need your value here, but if so, use it
  } else {
    success(value);
  }
}
```

Another possible solution, is using a class component. Classes components have exactly what you are describing.

```
myFunction = (myValue) => {
  this.setState({
    value: myValue,
  }, () => {
    // you can check state here because you are certain it was already updated

    if (this.state.value) { // some condition
      this.discard();
    } else {
      this.success(value);
    }
  }) 
}
```